# Any way to disable coded text on Skype?

Tags: skype

With one of the recent updates on Skype, we got introduced to a few new codes that we are able to use in order to change our text.

For example putting "!!" in front of a text will change it or by putting "~" twice in a sentence will strike the inbetween text.

My question is if there is a way to disable that since it starts to personally annoy me.

I don't want to use it to strike the text but to sound more 'sweet', let's say, or put some more emotion in it. The moment I use that symbol twice the inbetween text of that sentence gets striked.

I don't consider a 'solution' downgrading Skype's version.

Comment: Use italics or other word formatting instead of symbols. ~sweet~ doesn't sound sweeter than sweet to me, it looks like a 13 yr old girl typed it.

Comment: I don't remember telling that I'm not a 13 year old girl sexist fellow

Comment: In that case, use it like this: ~~sweet~~, nothing will be struck out.

Comment: They will still be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a double "!" followed with a space in front of the sentence will prevent that from happening even though it will slightly change the font of that sentence.